# Activity Monitor - Dock Icon - dual core is displayed with 4 columns

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

View > Dock Icon has two CPU choices:

- Show CPU Activity
- Show CPU History

I am on a dual core (MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014).
In both views, I see 4 items.

Using High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

While researching the Activity Monitor, I saw this:

[Some of the newer Macs have hyper-threading, which makes each core appear to be two processors.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2489996?answerId=12214513022#12214513022)

Relatively speaking, I'm less familiar with hyper-threading than older CPU technology, so I'm putting this in an answer, and letting the community vote.